# Google sync with iPhone causing incorrect dates on phone

Tags: iphone, google-calendar, google-sync

If I add a event in Google Calendar the time comes out wrong on the iPhone.

When I add an event on the iPhone the time on Google Calendar comes out wrong but the date is right?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the timezone in both the iPhone and Google Calendar.

In Google Calendar, it's in the first page of the settings.
In the iPhone, it's in `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > Time Zone Support` (at the bottom).

You should set both in the same timezone, then see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Wow its strange that you have to set the mail timezone and it is different from the clock time zone but nevertheless thanks very much!

Comment: @thelearner actually, I shorten the the title, it's "Mail, Contacts, Calendar". It has nothing to do with mails. Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my answer.

Comment: yeah I got what you meant, my only issue is why would I need to set the region for mail and then set the region for time - surely there should only be one setting - Apple weirdness

Comment: @TheLearner wait till you travel to another timezone, then you'll see weirdness... :P